# Unable to uninstall Java

Tags: java

I'm working with bat files, and I need to use Java 1.7. Unfortunately the output of:

```
@echo off
java -version
pause
```

is that I'm using Java 1.6.0_27b. I completely removed Java, and the directories do not exist anymore in Program Files (x86) nor Program Files. Why is it that the jvm still exists, and why is it pulling version 1.6? How can I go about removing it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you also have a `java.exe` file in your `%systemroot%` folder, i.e. `c:\windows`.

Answer (score 1):

Install the UnxUtils package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/. (Or Cygwin if you're feeling ambitious.) That will give you the `which` command, which you can use to determine exactly where that `java` is running from. Make sure you do `which java.exe` and not just `which java`.

```
C:\>which java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe
```

That will let you figure out where it's installed, and from there you can probably infer which distribution it is and how to uninstall it. The output of `java -version` should tell you who produced it, too, along with that version number. (Though the version "1.6.0_27b" pretty much means it's Sun/Oracle's.) Once you find the installation, you may be able to run an uninstaller from there, or you may be stuck manually removing the files and PATH entries.

Answer (score 0):

Run

> echo %path%

Make sure you don't have another folder of java somewhere other than the ones that you mentioned. Look out for java and jdk.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the location to the earlier java from your windows environment path variable.
To do so,

> a. Right-click MyComputer
>
> b. goto Properties
>
> c. Click on "Advanced System Settings" on the left hand upper side of
>   the window.
>
> d. Click on Environment Variables
>
> e. Check in the User Variables if there is a JAVA_HOME variable and
>   remove the same
>
> f. In the System Variable , double-click on PATH and and remove the
>   line that is specifying the the path to java1.6.
>
> g. Add the path to the new java i.e. 1.7 to the path.
>
> h. Check the same using fresh command line.

Comment: His question is " Why is it that the jvm still exists, and why is it pulling version 1.6? How can I go about removing it?" Your answer does not cover any of this.